# Saving Changes to sqlite database with xamarin forms

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core

As a project at school we are creating a mobile app using EF core with sqlite database. 
Following the MVVM pattern and SimpleIoc for dependency injection.

Everything works fine untill I call on the method dbContext.SaveChanges(); I have the following classes:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IUserService, UserService>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IUserRepository<User>, UserRepository>();

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<RegistrationPageViewModel>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<LoginPageViewModel>();
        }

        public RegistrationPageViewModel RegistrationVM => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<RegistrationPageViewModel>();
        public LoginPageViewModel LoginVM => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<LoginPageViewModel>();

    }
```

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext()
        {
            this.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source = C:\temp\SplitbillMobile.db") ;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

And when I get into my UserRepository class to add a user to the database:

```
public bool AddUser(User user)
        {
            try
            {
                var context = new DatabaseContext();

                context.Users.Add(user);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

When it tries to run context.SaveChanges(); it says that my context is null.
Or when I remove everything in my DatabaseContext class except OnConfiguring and the DbSet I receive following exception:
[image: exception]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What platform are you running this on?  `C:\temp\SplitbillMobile.db` is not a valid path for iOS/Android

Comment: Using Android platform

Comment: An Android device has no knowledge of the desktop filesystem.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows